How do I delete everything between two markers in files from the terminal on MacOS?
I am working with Mac Terminal and I would like to delete everything (in a large number of files) that is after KEYWORD1 and before KEYWORD2. I cannot use a substitution type of command because the content is not the same in the various files. I have tried various sed commands that I used to use with Linux but they do not work on Mac Terminal.

if your KEYWORD1 and KEYWORD2 are in the beginning of lines, you can use sed for this
sed -n '/KEYWORD1/,/KEYWORD2/p' file

this command prints result to stdout.
If you want to change the file, just add -i option
sed -i -n '/KEYWORD1/,/KEYWORD2/p' file


I could not get this to work. With the -n option it will print the result but it does not make the modification. With the -in option, it will create a new file with the same name and n attached at the end and with no modifications, while in the original file most lines are duplicated

Different sed implementations parse options differently. Try separating the options: -i -n

updated options, forgot that sed is too old to be fully compatible with posix, so lets try to use separate shortoptions
